# Google Reports API not giving Google Meet event participants joined time and leaving time

Tags: .net-core, google-calendar-api, google-admin-sdk, google-reporting-api, google-meet

I have a requirement to get the details of the google meet event. I am looking for join time and leaving of the participants of the completed google meet event.

What I tried:

I followed this doc https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/quickstart/dotnet and created service credential and I am able to get the activities of a particular user. Here is the doc for that gives details about the parameters returned for an activity
https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/appendix/activity/meet

but the parameters I am interested in(participants join time and leaving time) are not available.

Is there an API to get only particular event stats like meeting time, join time, leaving time etc?

FYI: I donot have any problem running the code, I am able to get the activities of the event.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After analyzing the audit logs for Google meet and also Gmeet Quality tool, the audit records has DateTime field can be considered as the Participant Joining time and the duration property in the payload can be added to the joining time to get the leaving time. If there are multiple dropout and joins, you will get those many records for that Participants.

Comment: Can you give me more documentation about procedure to get these data? I'm new in google api so i have a lot of thing still not know. Thanks so much

Answer (score 1):

### Apart from the [Google Meet Audit Activity Events](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/appendix/activity/meet), there is also the [Reports API: Customer Usage Metrics](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/appendix/usage/customer)

They allow you to access additional [Google Meet Parameters](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/appendix/usage/customer/meet) as specified in the documentation, however unfortunately there is no way to retrieve other parameters via API.

Comment: is it possible by any other means to retrieve participants join time and leaving time?

Comment: If you go to the Admin concole UI (`Reports->Audit log->Google Meet`) you will not see there the join time neither. However, you can retrieve the timestamp for the event `Endpoint left` and the parameter `duration` (also accessible via [API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/appendix/activity/meet)), so you can calculate the join time from this data.

Comment: It will be useful if the Participant joins the call only one time, if he drops and joins again and again, it will be difficult to understand this information. by the way, i couldn't find the timestamp for the event Endpoint Left

Comment: You can file a [feature request](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker) asking Google to add this data!